# Pegar elemento em ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema que a linha:

```
lista p = lista.get(i);
```

não quer pegar o elemento.

Olhem o método abaixo:

```
private void verPessoas() {
        ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> lista = new Read().getLista();

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            lista p = lista.get(i);
            System.out.println("#" + i + " Nome: " + p.getNome() + ", Idade: " + p.getIdade() + " anos, Peso: " + p.getPeso() + "Kg, Possui deficiencia? " + (p.isDeficiente() ? "SIM." : "NÃO.") + " UID: " + p.getUID());        

        if (pessoas.size() == 0) System.out.println("# Não existem registros.");
    }
```

Read:

```
import model.RespostasAguaCasa;

public class Read {
 public ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> getLista() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = Maindb.getInstancia().getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Maindb.TABELA;

    ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            RespostasAguaCasa resp = new RespostasAguaCasa(c.getString(0));

            resp.setValoragua(c.getInt(1));
            resp.setAcordar(c.getInt(2));
            resp.setDormir(c.getInt(3));
            lista.add(resp);
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
        {
        }
    }
    c.close();
    return lista;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Foca-te nesta linha:

```
ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> lista = new ArrayList<>();
```

O objeto lista é uma `ArrayList` de `RespostasAguaCasa`

O Problema está que na linha a seguir, confundes várias coisas:

```
lista p = lista.get(i);
```

1º atribuis dizes que a variável P é do tipo lista

2º, lista é uma variável que já foi atribuida(a tal ArrayList onde fazes o get)

Portanto o que tu queres é:

```
RespostasAguaCasa p = lista.get(i);
```

Comment: obrigado deu certinho

Comment: @AleanderRayson marca a resposta como aceite, para o tópico ser fechado!